# Border left is not showing up correcting for Paper MUI

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to have the border on the left of the CustomPaper in multiColor, meaning 50% of the height will be in green and the other in red,
But the problem is it only show the red border.
How can i fix this?

```js
import { Paper } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const CustomPaper = styled(Paper)`
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: red;
  }
`;
```

[image]